# Populate Dropdown with Values from ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a dropdown that I am trying to populate with the results from ActiveRecord. I guess I don't understand how to access the values that I'm retrieving because the code below is populating my dropdown with values like

`#<Product:0x007f1f488565b0>` which obviously isn't what I want.

```
<%= f.select :accessory, options_for_select(Product.select(:item_number, :id).where(:accessory=> 't') {|c| [ c.item_number, c.id ] }), {include_blank: true}, { :class => 'form-control'} %>
```

How can I populate the drop down with the item number and id? There is no relationship involved in this query. I just want a list of products that have are marked with a "t" for accessory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close :-)

The parameter for options_for_select should be an object with an enumerable of objects which responds to :first and :last

You are passing

```
Product.select(:item_number, :id).where(:accessory=> 't')
```

as parameter.
But my guess is that you want to pass

```
Product.select(:item_number, :id).where(:accessory=> 't')
  .map{|c| [ c.item_number, c.id ] })
```

You simply forgot to put the 'map'.

Ruby allows you to pass a block to any method, that's why you don't get any warnings or errors, but the block will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thank you Mark! 'Product.select(:item_number, :id).where(:accessory=> 't').map {|c| [ c.item_number, c.id ] }' worked.